# VBA Run-time error 3326: This recordset is not updateable on a crosstab query

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to output a crosstab query from Access to Excel, and I read that in 2010 it's better to use the OutputTo method as opposed to the TransferSpreadsheet method.  I have the following line of code, and sometimes it works flawlessly, and other times it kicks VBA run-time error 3326: This recordset is not updateable.  I'm not trying to update any data at all--I simply want to export the resulting data to Excel.

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "qryStates_1_Crosstab", "ExcelWorkbook(*.xlsx)", my_filename, False
```

Is there something else I need to be doing to make it output correctly?

Comment: I have the same problem, query does not update or write anything, it is a simple select that is exported to Excel.  Manually exporting the query seems to work fine.  Using DoCmd.OutputTo causes error 3326.

Answer (score 0):

## DoCmd

Make a temporary table with the results of the crosstab query:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT INTO tempTable FROM qryStates_1_Crosstab"
```

and then export the table to Excel instead of the query:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "tempTable", "ExcelWorkbook(*.xlsx)", my_filename, False
```

afterwards (or before the next export) either clear the data from the temp table:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM tempTable"
```

or just delete the table:

```
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "tempTable"
```

Each of these actions will popup warnings and confirmations.  If you don't want the warnings, you can toggle them off with:

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
```

just make sure to turn the warnings back *on* at or before the end of the sub:

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
```

`DoCmd` can do a lot more cool stuff too.   [Read up about it here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-object-access).

Comment: okay I just noticed that question is 3½ years old, I guess you're not still eager for an answer.  I thought I was browsing _new_ questions, lol

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and ashleedawg's answer worked, it just had a few typos:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT * INTO tempTable FROM qryStates_1_Crosstab"
```

Missing the asterisk

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputTable, "tempTable", acFormatXLSX, my_filename, False
```

acOutput type should be table, not query.  I used acFormatXLSX rather than the string style.  I don't know if that matters or not but it was already a part of the code I had typed so I let it stay when adapting her answer.